# Solution of $1+\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin x}+\tan x \geq 30$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Solve the given inequality:

$$1+\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin x}+\tan x \geq 30$$

I am trying to convert L.H.S. in terms of one trigonometric ratio but it is not happening here. Could someone suggest some other way to proceed?

Comment: by the look of it (didn't get too deep), did you try rewriting LHS as a function of, e.g. $\sin x = t$ and then solving it for $t$? You should get a quadratic expression

Comment: Start by plotting a graph. You find that the inequality is satisfied by $x$ in the intervals $[0,0.034449],[1.53747,\pi/2],[3.10723,\pi],[4.67669,3\pi/2]$. The expression has period $2\pi$, so these intervals repeat. Getting precise numbers is not straightforward. the polynomials are degree 6.

Answer (score 3):

Let $c = \cos(x)$, $s = \sin(x)$.  Expanding it out, using $\cos(2x) = 2 c^2 - 1$ and $\tan(x) = s/c$, you get equality when $2 c^3 - 29 c s + s^2 - c = 0$.
Eliminating $c$ using $c^2 + s^2 = 1$, we get a sextic equation for $s$:
$$ 4\,{s}^{6}+116\,{s}^{5}+834\,{s}^{4}-174\,{s}^{3}-836\,{s}^{2}+58\,s-1 = 0$$
This has Galois group $S_6$, so it isn't solvable by radicals: you aren't going to get a "closed-form" answer.  There are four real solutions, approximately 
$$ -.9993629412524186, 0.03436059828519417, 0.03444187797428862, .9994448453814450$$
The values of $c$ corresponding to these values of $s$ are approximately
$$ -0.03568909709301771, -.9994095002977926, .9994067025198521, 0.03331667811261415$$
These $(s,c)$  pairs correspond to the following $x$ values in $[-\pi,\pi]$:
$$ -1.606493004503501, 3.107225290399017, 0.03444869101765185, 1.537473482010302$$

The solutions of your inequality in $[-\pi, \pi]$ are then approximately$-1.606493004503501 \le x < -\pi/2$,
$0 < x \le 0.03444869101765185$, $1.537473482010302 \le x < \pi/2$, 
$3.107225290399017 \le x < \pi$.